# Who are the shareholders/owners/beneficiaries of the private component/aspect of the City of London Corporation?

Tags: england-and-wales, corporate-law, shareholders, city-of-london

Insofar as some parts of it (so called "[City's Cash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City%27s_Cash)") function as a private entity from monies "built up over the centuries" to such extent as to make it exempt from the Freedom of Information Act, then who controls these private components?

Comment: I've added a link to the question which includes some of the things the Cash is used for.

Answer (score 0):

See https://democracy.cityoflondon.gov.uk/documents/s162344/Citys%20Cash%20Annual%20Report%20Financial%20Statements%202020-21%20-%20ARM-FC.pdf:

> City’s Cash is a fund of the City of London Corporation
>
> ...
>
> City’s Cash is managed by committees of the City Corporation, with Membership of
> the committees drawn from the 25 Members of the Court of Aldermen and the 100
> Members of the Court of Common Council. Members of the Court of Aldermen and
> Court of Common Council are elected by registered voters (both residents and
> businesses) within the City of London. In determining appointments to
> committees, the Court of Aldermen and Court of Common Council will take into
> consideration, amongst other things, any particular expertise and knowledge of
> the Aldermen and Members.

Comment: That sounds like more along the lines of some board of directors or something that manage the entity's assets and affairs for the benefit of the shareholders. Whose benefit does the city's cash exist for?

Comment: @Seekinganswers The City of London corporation. It is fairly standard for endowments to exist as a separate corporate entity, to create a barrier to spending the principle.